# Expanding my ASP.NET solution to multiple sites ensuring maintainability

Tags: asp.net

I have a web site written in ASP.NET WebForms. I need to distribute the web site platform i have developet to another website - and this looks like i may have to do this a couple of times more.

Each website is running on its own SQL Server database and have a different layout. But each website shares codebase with the other sites.

Im looking for a way to lower the maintainability of these sites when i make changes or new features to the "main codebase". My concerns are how to update, preserving the layout (themes?) with a minimum of effort and (in a perfect world) choosing only which sites should get a particular upgrade. (eg. a bread crumb) - and keeping track of these.

Any feedback is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to learn [multi tiered architecture design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitier_architecture) for your web application.
There are many cool books and [ASP.NET 3.5 Application Architecture and Design](http://www.packtpub.com/application-architecture-and-design-for-asp-.net-3.5/book) is one of them.

Comment: Thanks, i already have this structure. What im looking for is deploying new/modified usercontrols/masterpages to each website